# Using sort() and cut() to segment numeric vector into groups

Tags: r

Here is the problem I'm attemptint to solve:

Create a function that inputs a vector of numeric grades (from 0 to 100) and outputs a vector of letter grades. Group grades A-D not by fixed cut-offs (e.g. A = scores 90 to 100), but by using a curve where 40% receive A's, 30% B's, 20% C's, 10% D's.

Here is what I've written thus far. It returns an error (see bottom). What is wrong with how I am tackling this?

```
  letter.grade <- function(grades){
  num.a <- .4*length(grades)
  num.b <- .3*length(grades)
  num.c <- .2*length(grades)
  num.d <- .1*length(grades)
  sort.grades <- sort(grades, decreasing = TRUE)
  cut(grades,
    breaks = c(sort.grades[0:num.a],sort.grades[num.a+1:num.b],
              sort.grades[num.b+1:num.c],
              sort.grades[num.c+1:num.d]),
    labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
  )
}
letter.grade(c(60, 39, 58, 36, 41, 44, 89, 17, 47, 63))
```

Error message:

```
Error in cut.default(grades, breaks = c(sort.grades[0:num.a], 
sort.grades[num.a +  : 'breaks' are not unique
```

Thanks!

Comment: `breaks` should be something like `c(0,60,70,80,90,100)` but we can't see what `breaks = c(sort.grades[0:num.a],sort.grades[num.a+1:num.b],
              sort.grades[num.b+1:num.c],
              sort.grades[num.c+1:num.d])` is, so you should `print` these and see what is going on

Comment: Take a look at what you're passing as `breaks`. Also, are you forced to use `sort` and `cut` or can you use something else?

Comment: @rawr - Sort.grades[] simply pulls the index # for the grades that fall in each category. First, I sorted all the grades from highest to lowest, then applied 40% to length(full.data.set) to see how many A's I should assign and I did this for all grade letters. I then dropped these index #s as "breaks" because the actual value where I break between each grade will vary based on the grades I input. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JuliánUrbano - No, I don't have to use cut(). I tried using several other methods and was unsuccessful. If you have a function or two you think I should try to use let me know. I would appreciate the direction/tip.

Comment: @jmo use the quantile function as suggested by Floo0

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
letter.grade(c(60, 39, 58, 36, 41, 44, 89, 17, 47, 63))
letter.grade <- function(grades){
  num.a <- .6*length(grades)
  num.b <- .3*length(grades)
  num.c <- .1*length(grades)
  sort.grades <- sort(grades, decreasing = FALSE)
  cut(grades,
    breaks = c(0,sort.grades[num.a],sort.grades[num.b],
              sort.grades[num.c],100),
    labels = c("D", "C", "B", "A")
  )
}
letter.grade(c(60, 39, 58, 36, 41, 44, 89, 17, 47, 63))
```

Note in particular that because you want four categories, you must specify five (not four) breaks (including the lower and upper limits), in the same way that if you want to lay 100m of fencing with a post every metre, you'll need 101 fence posts.

Answer (score 2):

Use `quantile()` and `cut()`:

```
letter.grade<-function(samp){
  q<-quantile(samp,c(1,0.6,0.3,0.1,0))
  res<-cut(samp,q,include.lowest=TRUE)
  levels(res)<-c("D","C","B","A")
  return(res)
}

letter.grade(c(60, 39, 58, 36, 41, 44, 89, 17, 47, 63))
[1] A C A C B B A D B A
Levels: D C B A
```

If you dont like res beeing a level use `as.numeric()`